# Cannot login to SDDM but to tty

Tags: login, pam, sddm

## Summary

On my kubuntu 16.04 I cannot login any more on the graphical login screen (produced by standard display manager SDDM). But when I switch to a tty I can login and start the graphical desktop with `startx`. Authentication is handled by `pam_unix` in both cases.

## Details

`journalctl` output of failed login to SDDM:

```
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm-greeter[1675]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm[1605]: Message received from greeter: Login
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm[1605]: Reading from "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop"
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm[1605]: Session "/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop" selected, command: "/usr/bin/startkde"
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: [PAM] Starting...
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: [PAM] Preparing to converse...
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: [PAM] Conversation with 1 messages
Jan 09 13:30:42 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: pam_unix(sddm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=bjhend
Jan 09 13:30:44 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: [PAM] authenticate: Authentication failure
Jan 09 13:30:44 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: [PAM] returning.
Jan 09 13:30:44 TS-DECO0004 sddm[1605]: Authentication error: "Authentication failure"
Jan 09 13:30:44 TS-DECO0004 sddm-greeter[1675]: Message received from daemon: LoginFailed
Jan 09 13:30:44 TS-DECO0004 sddm-helper[23916]: [PAM] Ended.
Jan 09 13:30:44 TS-DECO0004 sddm[1605]: Auth: sddm-helper exited with 1
```

Successful login on a tty:

```
Jan 09 13:46:03 TS-DECO0004 login[22121]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user bjhend by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jan 09 13:46:03 TS-DECO0004 systemd-logind[1432]: New session 39 of user bjhend.
Jan 09 13:46:03 TS-DECO0004 systemd[1]: Started Session 39 of user bjhend.
```

Calling `pam_unix` directly by `pamtester -v pam_unix bjhend authenticate` also works (without a `journalctl` message), provided I enter the correct password.

I cannot remember any problems between the last time of a successful graphical login and appearance of this problem. However, the last successful login was last year (2017) before my winter vacation and the problem appeared on my first login attempt this year after a fresh boot.

### Side observation

The digital clock on the SDDM login screen becomes scrambled after some time, such that the colon and some digits are missing. An attempt to login doesn't change that.

## Versions

All software are current packages of (k)ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS:

- `uname`: Linux 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- sddm: 0.13.0-1ubuntu5
- libpam-modules:amd64: 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2

## Question

Any ideas what could be the cause or how I can find out more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was a broken keyboard layout at login. Instead of the correct German layout the keyboard was set to US layout. So some special characters in the password were mapped to unexpected keys.

The problem is a known bug in the driver of wireless Logitech keyboards. Just before the problem appears I switched from a Microsoft to a Logitech wireless keyboard.

Unfortunately, the suggestion from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Unifying_Receiver to append `setxkbmap de` at the end of `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` did not help.

However, the suggestion at the end of https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=31639.0 to append `setxkbmap de` at the end of `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` worked for me. I'm not happy with this, because I don't like to change anything in `/usr` (except `/usr/local`) manually.