# Computer won't boot and display goes to sleep

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu

On a brand new HP EliteDesk 800 Small Form Factor PC (product 8YM57AV), I immediately installed Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS alongside the Windows 10 Pro installation that came with the computer. Installation appeared to complete successfully, but the computer has never booted up since then.

When the computer is powered on, the display wakes up, but after a few seconds it indicates that it is not getting any input, and it goes to sleep. I've tried holding various keys to either enter BIOS, select boot source, or check bootloader, and nothing happens. (Sometimes I get a beep from the computer, but not in a way I've been able to replicate.)

**Here's the most mysterious part: when I power down the computer by pressing the power button, the display wakes up and I am briefly greeted by the Kubuntu logo for about two seconds...and then the computer powers down.**

Since I can see absolutely nothing on the display, I'm really at a loss for how to troubleshoot this and will be grateful for any suggestions. (And the problem is definitely with the computer, as I've attempted this with several monitors that I know to be functional.)

***UPDATE:*** Today, on the umpteenth attempt at starting the computer while rapidly pressing F12, my computer booted into Kubuntu successfully. What a trip. Still have some kinks to iron out, obviously, but at least I have something to work with now. Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you install in UEFI mode? Or is Windows fast start up on? Then grub only has Ubuntu to boot and immediately tries to boot system. But if video issue or something else could be issue. What video card/chip? If UEFI, can you press escape key (perhaps more than once) after UEFI/BIOS screen but before you would normally get grub menu. And then if you get grub menu try booting recovery mode, second grub menu entry (may be in sub-menu).

Comment: @oldfred I believe fast start up is on. I usually never dual-boot and simply replace windows with Ubuntu, and I regret switching it up this time. The main issue is that I cannot see screens whatsoever. No UEFI/BIOS, no grub menu, nothing. The display immediately goes to sleep.

Comment: Fast Boot is an UEFI setting and can cause boot issues as it assumes no hardware configuration change & immediately boots. Fast start up is a "Windows setting that sets hibernation flag preventing Linux NTFS driver from fully mounting NTFS partitions.  While fast start up causes issues, it does not normally cause boot issues. It sounds like a video issue. Can you get recovery mode? Does live installer still boot?

Comment: @oldfred The video card is integrated. I can't get to recovery mode or boot from the live installer. The computer is currently a brick.

Comment: Have you tried switching TTY screens? I believe your GUI session is on TTY7 so CTRL+ALT+f7 but it may be on CTRL+ALT+f1 or CTRL+ALT+f2. You could try switching back and forth to see if that wakes it up. Alternatively, [are you using a non-US keyboard layout with an aftermarket keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1004605/167115)

Comment: Additionally, it's not a brick if you can login to one of your TTY screens, with your username and password, where you can then run commands. You can also check journalctl and other logs from the command line on one of those screens e.g., CTRL+ALT+f4 or CTRL+ALT+f5.

Comment: Also, my computer does this (immediately goes to sleep) and I have to move the mouse around after it completely boots to show the login screen. Additionally, on one of my computers, I have to unplug and plug the mouse back in after booting.

Comment: Have you updated to 20.04.3 which has newer kernel & drivers for new systems? It just came out. Or 21.04? HP 17-BY4063CL Laptop shows UEFI screens, needed 21.04 since new Intel chip
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045

Answer (score -1):

Do you have multiple video connections like HDMI? If so try switching the connections as it might be the connection to the monitor that's not working.

If still nothing you can reset your BIOS:

Turn on the computer and repeatedly press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key about once every second for eight seconds.

Press the Down arrow three times.

Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key two times.

The computer restarts.

You can even pull out the BIOS battery so it resets the BIOS to default.

Also check to make sure hard drive is plugged in all the way on both ends.